# How to get info from Firebase using a Map parameter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I have been using this type of calls from Firebase for a while, but I tried with a Map parameter and I am having problems:
This is the model:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Game {
  final Map<String, String> name;
  final String id;

  Game({
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'Name': name,
      'id': id,
    };
  }

  factory Game.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return Game(
      name: documentSnapshot['Name'],
      id: documentSnapshot['id'],
    );
  }
}
```

But the latest function isn't correct for Maps. How can I correct it so I'am able to use this provider and call at it in my pages:

```
class GamesStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Game>> {
  final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
  final String pathGame;

  StreamSubscription? _streamSubscription;

  GamesStateNotifier({
    required this.firebaseFirestore,
    required this.pathGame,
  }) : super([]);

  Future<void> init() async {
    _streamSubscription =
        firebaseFirestore.collection(pathGame).snapshots().listen((event) {
      state = event.docs.map((e) => Game.fromDocument(e)).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (_streamSubscription != null) {
      _streamSubscription!.cancel();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
}

final gamesStateNotfierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<GamesStateNotifier, List<Game>>((ref) {
  final firestore = ref.watch(InstanteGames);
  final path1 = ref.watch(PathGames);

  return GamesStateNotifier(
    firebaseFirestore: firestore,
    pathGame: path1,
  )..init();
});
```

Call in the page:

```
final gamesWatch = ref.watch(gamesStateNotfierProvider);
```

Comment: What is the value comes in `Name`?, add a collection tree

Comment: @AlexSunderSingh a collection tree ? Do you mean that I have to initiate values for the Map ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this on my .fromDocument function but the result is still the same error:

```
factory Game.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    final data = documentSnapshot.data();
    print(data);
    return Game(
      name: Map<String, String>.from(documentSnapshot['Name']),
      id: documentSnapshot['id'],
    );
  }
```

And the data printed is this one:

```
{id: 7f4FioRHNQPva2ESxGIs, Name: {Spanish: Yo nunca}}
```

I don'y know where the problem is, because the data received match.